# Primer on ActiveX Controls

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, ms-office

I would like to use an ActiveX control - almost exactly like [Edraw](http://www.edrawsoft.com/officeviewer.php) - to load and edit MS Word documents in IE.  I found [this MS article and FramerEx](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268470); can I use FramerEx?  How do I write the HTML to include FramerEx?

Also, can you point me to a primer on ActiveX controls?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FramerEx is sample code.  You can use it as a guide, but you'll probably need to re-write it to get it to production quality.  It's also probably not quite what you want.  I would recommend starting from scratch.

Refer to the [object tag documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535859(VS.85).aspx) to instantiate your control.

Here is [the primer on ActiveX controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751972(VS.85).aspx).